# How to change display value of items in data model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On the list of users, I would like to display the name of their role instead of roleId. Currently the data is loaded in the following form:

```
@model IEnumerable<DemoRes.Models.User>

<div id="divUsers">
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Access Role</th>
            <th>Enabled</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: List">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text : Username"></td>
                <td data-bind="text : Email"></td>
                <td data-bind="text : Role"></td>
                <td data-bind="text : IsActive"></td>
            <td>


</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The role property of User objects is an int value (0 - Admin, 1 - Member).

Currently in the form thus in the column "Access Role", integer value is displayed.

What I would like to do is **replace the integer value with belonging string (either "Admin" or "Member")**. Does anyone know what is the best way to accomplish that, given that the roles could be in general represented with arbitrary list or dictionary? How should the list (or dictionary) of roles be passed to form in this case (for example, using ViewBag, by modifying view model...)?

Thanks!

Comment: What client-side framework are you using? It should be possible to do with it

Comment: Create a property on the model (probably called something like `RoleName`) which returns the text value and bind to that instead.  Also, are you seriously ***displaying passwords***?  Are they ***plain text***?  Please, *please* don't do that.  That is quite possibly one of the most grossly irresponsible things you could do to your users.

Comment: Thanks David. The password is not going to be displayed and probably, it will be stored with encryption. Perhaps it's better to remove the field from example above :)

Answer (score 2):

Best practice here is to put it in the view model, then you can reference it in your knockout:

```
public string RoleName { get; set; }
```

Then populate it with your data (in your controller/business logic/model population code), then you can do:

```
<td data-bind="text : RoleName"></td>
```

As an aside from that, as @David mentioned, it looks like you're displaying passwords, which aside from the fact is **terrible security**, it also means that you're storing them unencrypted, which means that if someone gains access to your database, they get everyone's passwords, **not good**.